# Drawing a grid with coordinates in each cell onto existing image

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function that takes a JPG file, add a grid overlay, and in each cell write in text A1, A2, A3 and so on.

The current code (below) only draws the grid, with a static column/row size.

Question 1) How can I add the coordinates as text in each cell? E.g rows are letters, and columns are numbers. So first row is A1, A2, A3 ... and next row is B1, B2, B3.

Question 2) How can I modify it, so that I specify just how many rows and columns I want, and it will automatically adjust the size of the col/rows accordingly to fit the dimensions of the input image?

```
function draw_grid(&$img, $x0, $y0, $width, $height, $cols, $rows, $color) {
    imagesetthickness($img, 5);
    //draw outer border
    imagerectangle($img, $x0, $y0, $x0+$width*$cols, $y0+$height*$rows, $color);
    //first draw horizontal
    $x1 = $x0;
    $x2 = $x0 + $cols*$width;
    for ($n=0; $n<ceil($rows/2); $n++) {
        $y1 = $y0 + 2*$n*$height;
        $y2 = $y0 + (2*$n+1)*$height;
        imagerectangle($img, $x1,$y1,$x2,$y2, $color);
    }
    //then draw vertical
    $y1 = $y0;
    $y2 = $y0 + $rows*$height;
    for ($n=0; $n<ceil($cols/2); $n++) {
        $x1 = $x0 + 2*$n*$width;
        $x2 = $x0 + (2*$n+1)*$width;
        imagerectangle($img, $x1,$y1,$x2,$y2, $color);
    }
}

$imgpath = "foto/306/306.jpg";
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);
$size = getimagesize($imgpath);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];

$red   = imagecolorallocate($img, 255,   0,   0);
draw_grid($img, 0,0, $width /10 , $height /10 ,20,10,$red);

header("Content-type: image/jpg");
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: You are drawing only the required columns/rows to draw the grid, however, you'll make it extremely difficult to place text into those fields. Try drawing each individual rectangle, and placing the text there.

Comment: An alternative would be to build the grid with an old school html `<table>` (so with `<tr>` and `<td>` for the cells) and define your image as the table background. That way you can easily add text into each cells and get it formatted the way you want. Which is a lot more easier to do than using the `imagettftext()` rendering functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in my comment, your current code is only drawing the outlines. This is fine for drawing a Grid, but if you wish to add some text to the cell, you have to draw each rectangle manual, and use those coordinates to place the text.

---

Using [`imagettfbbox`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox), you can calculate the width/height of the text, you'll need that information to 'center' the text in to the cell.

---

Regarding your second question, dividing the total picture width with the number of cells you want so you'll know the size of each individual cell.

---

I've updated your code to show the general idea of calculation the x/y coordinates

```php
<?php

$imgpath = "duck.jpg";
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);
$size = getimagesize($imgpath);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];
$red   = imagecolorallocate($img, 255,   0,   0);

// Number of cells
$xgrid = 5;
$ygrid = 5;

// Calulate each cell width/height
$xgridsize = $width / $xgrid;
$hgridsize = $height / $ygrid;

// Remember col
$c = 'A';

// Y
for ($j=0; $j < $ygrid; $j++) {

    // X
    for ($i=0; $i < $xgrid; $i++) {

        // Dynamic x/y coords
        $sy = $hgridsize * $j;
        $sx = $xgridsize * $i;

        // Draw rectangle
        imagerectangle($img, $sx, $sy, $sx + $xgridsize, $sy + $hgridsize, $red);

        // Draw text
        addTextToCell($img, $sx, $xgridsize, $sy + $hgridsize, $hgridsize, $c . ($i + 1));
    }

    // Bumb cols
    $c++;
}

function addTextToCell($img, $cellX, $cellWidth, $cellY, $cellHeight, $text) {

    // Calculate text size
    $text_box = imagettfbbox(20, 0, 'OpenSans', $text);
    $text_width = $text_box[2]-$text_box[0];
    $text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1];

    // Calculate x/y position
    $textx = $cellX + ($cellWidth / 2) - $text_width;
    $texty = $cellY - ($cellHeight / 2) - $text_height;

    // Set color and draw
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 255);
    imagettftext($img, 20, 0, $textx, $texty, $color, 'OpenSans', $text);
}

// Save output as file
imagejpeg($img, 'output.jpg');
imagedestroy($img);
shell_exec('open -a Preview output.jpg');
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!!! I can make the rest of the adjustments myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help! Just noticed that the bottom line isn't visible. I didn't take into account the thickness of the line, you should subtract the line thickness from the total x/y!

Comment: That's no problem, the details is not important in my case. I've been using PHP for 10 years (for hobby projects), and had no idea $var++ was possible on strings :P
Only thing I'm unsure about is font size, should maybe be calculated based on image size. I guess I'll figure that out.

Comment: PHP will always amaze you, even after 10 years ;). You can read more about the `string++` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php). You should use it with care, `$n = 'z'; $n++; echo $n` will show `aa` ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Check out the [`imagettftext()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) and [`imagefttext()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php) functions. One of those should do what you want.

2) Divide the width and height of the input image by the number of columns and rows respectively that you want to divide it into to get the width and height of each cell.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm aware of imagettftext(), but I'm unsure about how I'm going to get the correct text aligned in the middle of the correct cells

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to get at the pixel width of the projected text. You'll probably have to determine that by trial and error.

Once you've got the cell width, divide it in half and subtract half of your estimate of the text pixel width. That should give you the offset for your text relative to the X coordinate of the current cell.